# C# database driven website, VS2008 & MSSQL guidance request

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I need a bit of guidance or pointing towards some tutorials for storing webpage content within a database and for that data to be displayed as and when requested.  I touched on storing data within grid views etc, but i cannot get my head around how i would store all the CSS and display alot of content in a web page style as opposed to grid view.

Whilst i understand the prinicples of the dynamic driven websites, i have been unable to find a real clear cut tutorial to guide me through the basic process.  For e.g. should i use data entities, or a list view etc?  I have my DB tables created, and my page layouts created i just need to store the data and call it when needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you building your own web server like Apache or is it more like archive.org? 

Another possibility is that I am misunderstanding your question and you simply want to display records in a database. If so, I would suggest [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) to get a basic data driven site up and running.

Comment: Thanks for your reply wtjones.  The current website is static and displays about 20 pages.  I want to be able to allow my members to edit the pages themselves either in or OOB therefore i would need to store the pages in a database and use content placeholders that link to specific arrays of the database.

Answer (score 1):

Why re-write something that has been done many times before? What you're looking for is a Content Management System; there are many to be had from free to costly, and I'm sure you could find something that would meet your needs.

Comment: I agree given a choice i would opt for Joomla or alfresco etc.  But the purpose of the project is for training purposes.